# Where is Google API FindPlace?

Tags: google-maps

FindPlace should be part of Places API, but I can't find it anywhere. It only shown on billing documentation.

> SKU: Find Place
>
> Find Place is charged for a Find Place request (new
>   feature, available in beta on June 11, 2018).

link: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use?hl=in#find-place

I guest it's still on beta? But is it closed beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Find place endpoint is publicly available since June 11, 2018. You can find corresponding documentation at

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests

You can use it, for example run the following query

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Sagrada%20Familia&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,place_id&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You will get the following response

```
{
    "candidates":[
        {
            "formatted_address":"Carrer de Mallorca, 401, 08013 Barcelona, Spain",
            "name":"La Sagrada Familia",
            "place_id":"ChIJk_s92NyipBIRUMnDG8Kq2Js"
        }
    ],
    "debug_log":{
        "line":[

        ]
    },
    "status":"OK"
}
```

Corresponding documentation for Maps JavaScript API can be found at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_requests

I hope this helps!